# Regex to not start characters and then follow with pattern

Tags: regex

How to write regex for pattern not start with char1 or char2 then followed by different string1 or string2 patterns.

For example, not start with " or ), then followed by cat and dog

(cat <- valid

"cat <- invalid, because it starts with "

) dog <- valid

I tried `^(?!\"|\))` to not start with.

Comment: Try `^[^")]\s*(cat|dog)\b` or ``^(?![")].*?\b(cat|dog)\b``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most regex implementations, you can use `[^xyz]` to denote "anything but x, y, or z". So in your case, you could use `[^\"\)](cat|dog)` for a single character (except two forbidden) followed by "dog" or "cat". The backslashes ensure the characters are interpreted literally.

Comment: Good answer, but the backslashes are not necessary.  Characters inside a character class are assumed to be literal, unless the character is `-` or `]`.

Comment: This answer is wrong because it won't match `cat` nor `dog` at the start of string.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```js
(?<![")])(?:cat|dog)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/fRIQ8j/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [")]                     any character of: '"', ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cat                      'cat'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    dog                      'dog'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```